# Laravel Task Scheduling on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I have a laravel 5.1 application, and i deployed my work on a shared hosting unix server. My application contains a task schedule (Cron Job). I need to know how to run this task after deploying to the shared server.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be answered by the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to see if your shared hosting provider allows you to run cron jobs.

If it does, then you can add a single cron and use the [Scheduling feature in Laravel (5.1+)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling).

If not, then you're probably out of luck.